# How can I know where a variable is being initialized

Tags: java, spring

We are using J2EE with Spring in our application.
I have this piece of code in my application:

```
public class StreamThread extends Thread implements Constants{
{
    private Set<String> allsymbolSet= new HashSet<String>();
    boolean switchTab(String tab) throws Exception 
    {
        if (somecondition) {
            SymbolsSet = allsymbolSet;
        }  
    }
}
```

The question may be funny, but I'm still trying my luck.
I have no idea how the `allsymbolSet` is being set.

How is it possible to know where the value `allsymbolSet` is being initialized?
This `allsymbolSet` is not static or constant; it varies from user to user.

Is there any configuration in Spring like that?

Comment: How this question has any relationship with Spring?

Comment: changed your title and retagged your question, as it has nothing to do with Spring.  And, your code is not valid too.  What is the meaning of `Symbolset = allsymbolSet` ? I cannot see corresponding variable declaration

Comment: Is it a Spring bean? What web framework? Need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is honestly very unclear.  I try to guess what you are trying to ask

```
public class Foo {
{
    private Set<String> bar = new HashSet<String>();   // 1

    public void doSomething() {
        assert bar != null;  //2
    }
}
```

At line 1, it is obviously bar is initialized (with `new HashSet<>()`).  Given that assert in line 2 is not failing, that means line 1 is somehow executed beforehand.  Is it what you are going to ask?:

> When will the initialization of line 1 be executed?

If it is, then you can simply treat it as: logic of field initialization and initialization block will be automatically "copied" to beginning of all constructors, after the super class constructor invocation.

Use this as an example:

```
public class Foo {
{
    private Set<String> bar = new HashSet<String>();   // 1

    {   // initializer
        bar.add("BAR");
    }

    public Foo() {
       someInitLogic();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        assert bar != null;  //2
    }
}
```

The compiler will generate code for you to make it looks like:

```
public class Foo {
{
    private Set<String> bar;


    public Foo() {
        super();      // auto-generated invocation of superclass ctor
        bar = new HashSet<String>();   // field initialization and 
        bar.add("BAR");                // initializers

        someInitLogic();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        assert bar != null;  //2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Where* is it set?

```
private Set<String> allsymbolSet= new HashSet<String>(); // Right here.
```

*When* is it set?  [When the instance is created](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2).  From the Java Language Specification:

> If a field declarator contains a variable initializer, then it has the
>   semantics of an assignment (§15.26) to the declared variable, and: ...
>
> - ...If the declarator is for an instance variable (that is, a field that is not static), then the variable initializer is evaluated and
>     the assignment performed each time an instance of the class is created
>     (§12.5).

The reason it works this way is that you're only dealing with a POJO with `allSymbolSet`.  It's not being wired by XML or a constructor argument, nor is it `@Autowired` (which would be **bizarre**), so whenever an instance of `StreamThread` is created, so is that instance variable.